# Android White Screen

Tags: java, android, xml, android-webview

I use Android Studio for making a webview it works perfectly in some phones but in some others when I open the application just see white screen. Why it happens?

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.location.reload( true )");



    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
    webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); //zoom yapılmasına izin verir
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());


    webView.loadUrl("https://www.stebilisim.com");
```

Comment: try this `<WebView
    android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layerType="hardware"/>`

Comment: You can change `android:layerType` in your xml code and try it .

Comment: okay thank you @KeLiuyue

Comment: Good luck to you~

Answer (score 1):

Try this .

```
<WebView 
    android:id="@+id/web_view" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layerType="hardware"/>
```

You can use `android:layerType` in your xml code .